# PDO error sql state 42000

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have query function in model:

```
public function query($qry, $params = array()) {
        try {
            $pdo = $this->prepare($qry);
            $pdo->execute($params);

            return $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            return '<div class="error message">' . $e->getMessage() . '</div>';
        }
    }
```

Where I want to INSERT some data to table with this code:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$key = $this->key_generator();
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

$qry = "
    INSERT INTO users 
    (email, password, key) 
    VALUES (:email, :password, :key)
";

$params = array(
    ':email' => $email, 
    ':password' => $password, 
    ':key' => $key
);

$result = $this->query($qry, $params);
```

Note: this is only testing code ...

I catch exception:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES
```

I can't figure out where is syntax error near `key)`.

Comment: `KEY` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You need to quote it with backticks to use it as a column name.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thank you, I am new in PDO, bookmarked reserved keyword page. Since now I will use backtick for everything to be sure. If you want, create answer, so I can add you some points.

Comment: I don't need the points. Accept whatever answer you get below.  You really don't need to backquote every column name -- a better and common strategy is to learn what the reserved words are and then avoid using them as column & table names, so you sidestep the problem. That said, most frameworks which construct queries will backquote all identifiers to be safe. Personally, when hand-coding, I would rather avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use backtick(`) symbol to enclose every column name since it may contain the mysql key word in your query; password and key are keywords of mysql.